What does "qualify" mean with regard to presidential succession?
3 U.S.C. § 19(b) states "If...the Speaker fails to qualify as Acting President, then the President pro tempore of the Senate shall...act as President," and 19(d) says "If, by reason of...failure to qualify, there is no President pro tempore to act as President under subsection (b) of this section, then the officer of the United States who is highest on the following list...shall act as President." However, 19(e) spells out that subsections (b) and (d) only applies to officers who are constitutionally eligible to be president, which implies to me that "fails to qualify" is referring to other qualifications outside the Constitution. What other qualifications is this referring to? Or am I misreading this and 19(e) is just redundant for the Speaker and President pro tempore?

The Constitution provides for these requirements for a candidate to qualify for the office of the President:

No Person except a natural born Citizen, or a Citizen of the United States, at the time of the Adoption of this Constitution, shall be eligible to the Office of President; neither shall any Person be eligible to that Office who shall not have attained to the Age of thirty five Years, and been fourteen Years a Resident within the United States.

For the House of Representatives the qualifications are:

No Person shall be a Representative who shall not have attained to the Age of twenty five Years, and been seven Years a Citizen of the United States, and who shall not, when elected, be an Inhabitant of that State in which he shall be chosen.

The Constitution doesn't provide any special qualifications for the office of the Speaker, so conceivably anyone qualified to be a member of the House can be its speaker. In fact, there were discussions during the last congress of appointing Donald Trump as the speaker, and he wasn't even a member of the House.
Similarly, for Senate:

No Person shall be a Senator who shall not have attained to the Age of thirty Years, and been nine Years a Citizen of the United States, and who shall not, when elected, be an Inhabitant of that State for which he shall be chosen.

So a person can be a member of the Congress (House or Senate) while not being qualified to be a President (either because of age, residency, or because of citizenship), even if elected to be the Speaker or President pro tempore.
There are no special constitutional requirements for a Cabinet position other than a Senate confirmation, so similarly any other candidate in the line of succession may not qualify.
Subsection (e) clarifies that limitation.

Also, the 22nd amendment adds term limits:

No person shall be elected to the office of the President more than twice, and no person who has held the office of President, or acted as President, for more than two years of a term to which some other person was elected President shall be elected to the office of the President more than once.

However it restricts the qualification for election, conceivably one may end up acting as a President under 3 USC 19 even after completing two terms (e.g.: a past 2-term president elected to be the Speaker and then succeeds). Whether the limitation of the 22nd amendment applies in such a case is probably going to be determined when such an unlikely situation arises.

I understand the need for subsection (e) with regard to cabinet members, but my question is specifically about subsections (b) and (d) specifying that a Speaker or President pro tempore who "fails to qualify" not being eligible for succession, and why subsection (e) seems to redundantly enforce the same requirement on them. Are you saying that it just is redundant with regard to the Speaker and President pro tempore? That (avoiding (d) for now) if subsection (e) didn't specify that it applied to subsection (b), then there would be no difference in the law with regard to the Speaker?

Not sure why you think it's redundant. It codifies the constitutional requirement.

Right, but my question is then under what circumstances would the Speaker "[fail] to qualify as Acting President" other than the constitutional requirements for President? It's the phrasing that gets me: subsection (e) doesn't say it's defining qualifications, it says that subsection (b) as a whole doesn't apply to a Speaker that doesn't meet the constitutional requirements, which implies to me that "fails to qualify as Acting President" is referring to something other than the constitutional requirements.

They may potentially decline, refuse to take the oath, and whats not. But I'm still confused why being ineligible is not a failure to qualify in your view.

Oh, no, I assumed it would be? That's why I thought it was weird that subsection (e) had to state explicitly that it applied to subsection (b). It seemed to me like "fail to qualify" should just mean being constitutionally ineligible, but the fact that subsection (e) had that call out at all made me think I was wrong about that and that "fail to qualify" must mean something else I couldn't think of. But now I think I must've just been reading too much into the structure of how the statute was written.

(b) sspecifically mentions the Speaker from (a) not qualifying, but (d) has no similar qualification about (b). I think it's simply a redundancy that the eligibility requirement for Speaker is in both (b) and (e).

"The Constitution provides for these requirements for a candidate to qualify for the office of the President" But the people in the Presidential Succession Act wouldn't hold the office of President. They would be "acting" as President, i.e. they would become "Acting President".

@user102008 I don't think it's been litigated, but "acting as" means being in the office. So far the only precedents we had were vice president successions.

@littleadv: There's a difference between becoming President and acting as President. e.g. the Constitution says that when the President dies or resigns, the VP "becomes" President, but when the President is unable to discharge duties, the VP only "acts" as President. There have been several times when VPs acted as President for a few hours under section 3 of the 25th Amendment. I wouldn't say that they held the "office" of President during those times; they held the office of VP and only had the powers of the President.

@littleadv: The Constitution says people beyond the VP can only "act" as President (regardless of whether it is due to vacancy or disability of the President and VP), so in my opinion, in such a case, they do not hold the "office" of President.

Well.... Given that it never happened and was never litigated we can both hold opposite opinions and consider ourselves right. I can see how your argument could prevail in the current SCOTUS in case the "correct" otherwise ineligible candidate to succeed is presented (after all, they're not shy of making things up as it suits them), however it would most definitely go against the founding fathers' spirit of limiting access to the Presidential power to only certain eligible individuals.

@littleadv: Not sure what you mean by "ineligible candidate". The current Presidential Succession Act only allows people who are eligible for the office of President to act as President. I don't see Congress ever changing that.

Subsections (b) and (d) say what happens when the Speaker of the House and President pro tempore of the Senate, respectively, "fails to qualify as Acting President", but it does not explain what would make someone fail to qualify as Acting President. Nowhere in the Constitution does it provide what would make someone "fail to qualify as Acting President". The Constitution provides qualifications to be President and Vice President, but Acting President is not the President. The Constitution provides that Congress provide by law who shall "act as President" in the case of disability of both the President and Vice President, but the Constitution does not require that the person Congress provides as Acting President meet the same qualifications as President.
Subsection (e) is not redundant because it provides something that would make someone fail to qualify as Acting President under the Act. But subsection (e) doesn't say what happens when the Speaker and/or the President pro tempore fails to qualify, so subsections (b) and (d) are not redundant because they provide what happens when the Speaker and/or the President pro tempore fails to qualify due to subsection (e).
